# C order of passing Arguments . How is this code is working?

Tags: c

**CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int a =1;
    printf("%d%d%d%d\n",a,++a,++a,a);

    a=1;
    printf("%d%d%d%d\n",a,a++,++a,a);

    a=1;
    printf("%d%d%d\n",a,++a,a++);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
3333
3233
331
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is undefined behaviour - the evaluation order of arguments is unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

This is "undefined behavior".  You cannot rely on the order of evaluation of function arguments in C.  When we say "undefined behavior" we mean that anything might happen: it might work on one compiler, it might not work on another compiler; it might work on one compiler with optimizations disabled, and not work on the same compiler with optimizations enabled; it might not work at all; it might work flawlessly; it might dump core; it might send sperm whales and bowls of petunias falling from the sky.

(See https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-passage-on-the-whale-and-the-bowl-of-petunias-about)

Comment: And since that quora link doesn't specify, this is a reference to [Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/chosen-one-of-the-day-the-falling-bowl-of-petunias-in-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank you for the far more useful link.

Comment: @MikeNakis why to answer the most common duplicte here\

Comment: @P__J__ because I have always wanted to find an opportunity to mention sperm whales and bowls of petunias!